# What is the idiomatic way to use current_scope or create a new one in model's class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use `to_csv` method in a chain like this `Company.where(created_at: '2010-01-01').limit(20).to_csv`

To do so, I use `current_scope` and it works fine. But when calling the same method like this `Company.to_csv` it complains because `current_scope` is nil.

Right now I'm using `(current_scope || where(true))` which does the trick for me, but maybe there's a "proper" way to do it?

```
  def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      (current_scope || where(true)).includes(:_address).each do |company|
        csv << company.attributes
      end
    end
  end
```

Ps. I know I could just use `current_scope` and call `Company.all.to_csv`, but this is not what's this question is about.

Comment: What is `current_scope`?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to the party. I was trying to find the method corresponding to `current_scope` and stumbled upon your question (and found my precious `current_scope` method, so thank you).

I think for your case, you could have just written:

```
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    includes(:_address).each do |company|
      csv << company.attributes
    end
  end
end
```

You dont have to use `current_scope` method as Rails already does that for you.

If you are wondering why I had to go looking for `current_scope`, I had to chain to current_scope like an n number of times, see this:

```
def self.search(terms)
  terms = Array(terms)
  return all if terms.blank?
  filtered = current_scope || all
  terms.each do |term|
    filtered = filtered.search_scope(term)
  end
  filtered
end

def self.search_scope(term)
  # logic for scope on 1 term 
  # returns a scope
end
```

So I could call like this: `MyModel.search(['test1', 'test2']).limit(5)` or `MyModel.limit(5).search('test')`

Comment: Could you help me out and explain exactly what current_scope is doing that differs from all?  Looking at the code, it seems like all clones the scope and then ... well I had trouble following.  Thanks.